# Created the AVD but still error ON RUNNING THE APP IN EMULATOR

Tags: android

i am new to Android development, i have installed Android studio 3.1 and Oreo 8.1. I have created an AVD also but still having error when i try to run my app in emulator. Your responses would be a great help.
Thank you

Comment: share the error

Comment: THERE are few like - EXit code 1, process was killed and use list of words

Comment: i used to change Software as well. But it didn't work

Comment: try using software graphics for emulator instead of hardware and automatic

Comment: i used that also.....but didnt work

Comment: can you share the screenshot of exact error

Comment: finally i got it....Thank you but having some errors again